# Automatic checking of jstl fmt:messages?

Tags: internationalization, jstl, automated-tests

Is there any automatic way to check that all referenced messages in my jstl are, in fact, provided in a properties file?

Of course I always add in translations as I make references to them, but I'm mainly concerned about the rare instance where I forget one, or have a typo in either the fmt:messages tag or the properties file; if it is a message that isn't displayed often (e.g. an unusual error message), then I may not realize it until someone gets the error with a ???errormessagename??? which is no good!)

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a default property. 
With that you will avoid ???Property_Key??? messages.

But I recently had the same need.
I've made a Excel sheet with automatic merging.

The way I did it is:

1. Past the first property file content on a first sheet
2. Same for second on an other sheet
3. Create a macro parsing each lines, with making a split on the "=" the identify the key.
4. Put the key of sheet1 on a third sheet
5. Parsing sheet2 and try to match with keys in sheet3
6. iF no matches, there is a translation mission, put key in a fourth sheet.

I know it's not a perfect tool, but it's realy helpfull.